SQL Update affecting more rows than expected from a query
I worked on a SELECT query that returned 2 rows when I was testing on my db :
SELECT c.CandidateId
FROM Candidate c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CandidateId, MAX(UpdateDate) AS MaxDateStatut
    FROM StatusHistory
    GROUP BY CandidateId
) hs ON c.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
INNER JOIN StatusHistory hs2 ON hs.CandidateId = hs2.CandidateId AND hs.MaxDateStatut = hs2.UpdateDate
INNER JOIN InstitutionCandidate ic ON ic.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
WHERE hs2.StatusId = 2 AND ic.IsActive = 1

For the purpose of updating all of them with an UPDATE statement such as :
UPDATE InstitutionCandidate
SET IsActive = 0
WHERE CandidateId IN (
    SELECT c.CandidateId
    FROM Candidate c
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT CandidateId, MAX(UpdateDate) AS MaxDateStatut
        FROM StatusHistory
        GROUP BY CandidateId
    ) hs ON c.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
    INNER JOIN StatusHistory hs2 ON hs.CandidateId = hs2.CandidateId AND hs.MaxDateStatut = hs2.UpdateDate
    INNER JOIN InstitutionCandidate ic ON ic.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
    WHERE hs2.StatusId = 2 AND ic.IsActive = 1
);

It said "20 rows affected". What could explain this? This is a local database so nobody else is using it. Did I somehow change the WHERE condition that I'm not realizing?
EDIT:
I'm testing this by Inserting a row such as this :
INSERT INTO InstitutionCandidate
VALUES (1, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 74, 1)

after executing this, and then executing my UPDATE, I get a "21 rows affected" (then "0 rows affected" if I do it again), and then I execute the INSERT INTO again, then the UPDATE, and then I get "22 rows affected" and so on.

the queries are not necessarily equivalent so it can definitely happen.  your update doesn't take care of InstitutionCandidate rows that are already IsActive = 0 for example, so both 1 and 0 can get updated

@siggemannen you're right, I just realized it is also updating those where IsActive = 0. I thought the WHERE ic.IsActive = 0 near the end would take care of that, where do I need to put it to skip them?

The inner InstitutionCandidate rows are limited by IsActive = 1, but the outer InstitutionCandidate rows seleceted for update are not limited by the ``IsActive` value.

I see, I added a AND IsActive = 1 at the very end and it seems to work fine now. Thanks

You can modify your initial select statement by just changing the SELECT clause to UPDATE ic SET ... to update the already-referenced InstitutionCandidate rows (aliased as ic).  Something like:
UPDATE ic
SET IsActive = 0
FROM Candidate c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CandidateId, MAX(UpdateDate) AS MaxDateStatut
    FROM StatusHistory
    GROUP BY CandidateId
) hs ON c.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
INNER JOIN StatusHistory hs2 ON hs.CandidateId = hs2.CandidateId AND hs.MaxDateStatut = hs2.UpdateDate
INNER JOIN InstitutionCandidate ic ON ic.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
WHERE hs2.StatusId = 2 AND ic.IsActive = 1

Also, as an alternative to using the GROUP BY subquery and following JOIN to identify the latest status, you can use the CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...) pattern to get the latest status for each candidate.
UPDATE ic
SET IsActive = 0
FROM Candidate c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 sh.*
    FROM StatusHistory sh
    WHERE sh.CandidateId = c.CandidateId
    ORDER BY sh.UpdateDate DESC
) sh1
INNER JOIN InstitutionCandidate ic ON ic.CandidateId = hs.CandidateId
WHERE sh1.StatusId = 2 AND ic.IsActive = 1

(Note that the sh1.StatusId = 2 condition needs to be outside of the CROSS APPLY because we want the latest status, regardless of value, and once we have it, filter the result set by StatusId = 2.)
